# Serre's criterion for normality & Depth of local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ a field and consider the ring $A=k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x)$.
I try to show that $R$ is normal, that means that $R$ is
integrally closed with respect it's quotient field $F= Frac(A)$.
One approach which I already know is to use the theory of
algebraic curves. Then the result follows for $k$ good enough
from Jacobian criterion for smoothness.

As an alternative approach I want to understand the
[Serre's criterion for normality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre%27s_criterion_for_normality):
$A$ is normal <=> $R_1,S_2$ hold.

Generally $R_k$ means $A_p$ is a regular local ring for any prime
ideal $p$  of height $≤ k$ and

$S_k$ that $depth \ A_p \ge \inf\{k,ht(p) \}$ for any prime
ideal $p$.

The *depth* of a $R$-module $M$ is defined as the length of the maximal
regular sequence. For a local ring $A_p$
with maximum ideal $p$ the depth of $A_p$
is the depth of $p$ recognized as a $A_p$ module.

My question concerns the verification of $S_2$ for $A$.
If we start with an $R$-module $M$ and a
regular element $m \in M$, is that always possible to extend this $m$
to a maximal regular sequence with lenght $=depth_R(M)$?

Applied to situation here I want to find out if for every prime ideal
$p$ of $R$ the depth bahaves "well" with quotients and localizations
in the sense that the depth of
local ring $k[x,y]_p$ is exactly by $1$ bigger then the depth of
$(k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3+x))_p$?

Comment: You factorize by a regular element, so there is  no reason to worry about depth.

Comment: The question is *why* this behave well. A formal argument?

Comment: Have you tried to consider a noetherian local ring R and a regular element x and show that the depth of R/(x) drops by 1?

Comment: not yet but it seems to run in correct direction (...will prove it tomorrow since tired now =) ) .And it seems that the localizations of $k[x,y]$ wrt primes $p$ also not cause problems since if a ring has no zero divisors then it's localizations too. In other words $y^2-x^3+x$ is regular in all localizations $k[x,y]_p$. I think that modulo the issue on depth dropping of $R/(x)$ with these consideration we can conclude that $A$  satisfies $S_2$ immediately. Thank you!

Comment: In fact, it satisfies $S_n$ since it is a Cohen-Macaulay ring.