# Comparison of Depths of local rings $A_p$ and $(A/(a))_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $a \in A$ a regular element
that is a non zero divisor.

Consider now a prime ideal $p \subset A$ which contains $a$. In other
words $p$ is a prime ideal of $A/(a)$. We are going to compare
*depths* of local rings $A_p$ and $(A/(a))_p$ which result from $A$ and $A/(a)$
after localization at prime ideal $p$.

Which sufficient and necessary conditions on ring $A$ should be imposed
such that for every prime ideal $p$ containing $a \in A$ the depths are
related as

$$ \tag{1} depth((A/(a))_p= depth(A_p)-1 $$

few remarks on definitions:

- The depth of a $R$-module $M$ is defined as the length of the
  maximal regular sequence. For a local ring $A_p$ with maximum
  ideal $p$ the depth of $A_p$ is the depth of $p$ recognized as a $A_p$ module.
- the question is closely related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776169/serres-criterion-for-normality-depth-of-local-ring). As user26857 explaned a
  sufficient condition is to require that $A$ is Cohen-Macaulay ring,
  since for regular $a \in A$ is then also Cohen-Macaulay. But of course
  Cohen-Macaulay is a strong property and there are a lot of interesting rings which are not Cohen- Macaulay and I would like to know if we can replace
  the requirements for $A$ to be Cohen-Macaulay but something weaker such that equation (1) nevertheless is true for all primes.

Comment: First: regular = non zero divisor.

Comment: Second: I said S_n holds for that ring since it is CM.

Comment: Third: I suggested you to prove the present claim without any reference to CM.

Comment: Fourth: a regular element remains so in any ring of fractions, so involving a prime here is an unnecessay complication, that is, you may assume A local.

Comment: Fifth: the answer is yes. Prove it!

Comment: I tried, one direction is easy, another not really 
(at least for me).
As you said we can assume $A$ local since any regular
element stays regular in localized ring $A_p$. 
Let $a \in A$ a regular element, $n =depth(A)$, and we 
have to show $depth(A)-1=depth(A/(a))$. Since $n$ is maximal
lenght of all possible regular sequences of $A$, 
the maximal regular sequence $a:=b_1, b_2,..., b_m$ extending 
$a$ can have lenght at most $n$ so $depth(A/(a))
\le n-1=depth(A) -1$. Why is another inequality also true?
Can it be proved with preferably non homological methods? Do you have a hint?

Comment: Start with a maximal regular sequence $\bar b_1,\dots,\bar b_m$ in $A/(a)$ and show that the sequence $a,b_1,\dots,b_m$ is maximal in $A$. Eventually you can use that an ideal consists of zero-divisors iff it is contained in an associated prime.

Comment: Let me clarify the problem I see trying to elaborate you hint:
Let $n=depth(A)$. Assume that as you 
said $\bar b_1,\dots,\bar b_m$ is a maximal regular sequence
in $A/(a)$ then $a, b_1,..., b_m$ for a regular sequence 
in $A$. Now the problem I see is if *every* regular
sequence in $A$ can be completed to a maximal one in "strong
sense"? What I mean by strong sense?
So what I try to say is that if we start with an arbitrary
regular sequence $c_1,c_2,...,c_d$ in $A$ then 
clearly this sequence can

Comment: be extended to a "maximal" sequence
$c_1,...,c_{n'}$ with respect this "initial sequence"
$c_i, 1 \le i \le d$ in the sense that if we add 
a further element $c_{n'+1}$ then this sequence would not more
regular or equivalently there as no $c_{n'+1} \in A$ with
$c_{n'+1}$ regular in $A/(c_1,...,c_{n'})$. Let call such 
extension an extension "in weak sense". 
On the other hand is it always possible to extend an initial sequence
to a maximal sequence in "strong sense", that means that
moreover $n'=n$?

Comment: Back to our proof: assume we extend the sequence
$a= a,b_1,..., b_m$ in weak sense to $a, b_1,..., b_{n'}$. 
The claim is that $m=n'$ since otherwise 
$\bar b_1,\dots,\bar b_{n'}$ would be regular sequence
in $A/(a)$, that's a contradiction.

Back to the problem I explaned above: If we know that 
$n'=n$ (equivalently any regular sequence can be extended
to maximal seq in strong sense), we are done, 
but I don't understand why this is always possible.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't follow you.

Comment: What means that $\bar b_1,\dots,\bar b_m$ is a maximal regular sequence in $\bar A=A/(a)$? This means that $\bar m=m/(a)$ is an associated prime of $\bar A/(\bar b_1,\dots,\bar b_m)=A/(a,b_1,\dots,b_m)$, that is, $\bar m$ equals the annihilator of an element $\bar c$, or if you like $\bar m\bar c= \bar 0$. This implies that $mc\subseteq(a,b_1,\dots,b_m)$, that is, $m$ is an associated prime of $A/(a,b_1,\dots,b_m)$. This shows that the regular sequence $a,b_1,\dots,b_m$ is maximal.

Comment: As a.side remark, $A$ must be noetherian in order to define depth.

Comment: I think the problem was that I used another definition 
for maximality of a regular sequence. I used the definition
that for local ring $A$ a regular sequence $a_1,...,a_k$
is maximal if it cannot be extended properly to a longer
regular sequence. That is there is no $a_{k+1} \in A$ such
that $a_{k+1}$ is regular in $A/(a_1,...,a_k)$.
And at first glance this definition not guarantees 
that two such regular sequences $a_1,...,a_k$ and
$b_1,...,b_l$ which are maximal in the sense above have same
length, that is that $k=l$?

Comment: that's exactly what I called "maximal in weak sense"
in my previous comments. Of course if we use the definition
on maximal regularity 
which you used, namely that $a_1,...,a_k$ maximal regular iff
$m \subset A$ is associated prime of $A/(a_1,...,a_k)$, 
then I understand your argument.

Comment: Last question: Do you know how to prove that these two
definitions of maximal regular sequence coincide?

Comment: If every element of an ideal is a zero-divisor, then the ideal is contained in the set of all zero-divisors which is the union of associated primes. By prime avoidance this means that the ideal is contained in an associated prime.

Comment: Thank you very much!